# How to get Aspect to fire for annotated functions?

Tags: java, annotations, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to learn about Aspects and custom annotations by completing a very simple function that logs the execution time of a function.  I have the following aspect and annotation and annotated function, but when I call the annotated function, the aspect code does not get called. How do I tie the annotation to the aspect?

Also I tried just declaring the file an aspect not a class with @Aspect, and also removing the '@annotation(Benchmark)' and not trying to pass in the annotation but it never seems to work.

@Benchmark Annotation:

```
package net.tia.util.aspects;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Benchmark {
    public boolean logReturnValue() default false;
    public String description() default "";
}
```

Aspect

```
package net.tia.util.aspects;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.text.MessageFormat;


@Component
@Aspect
public class BenchmarkAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BenchmarkAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "@annotation(Benchmark)")
    public Object benchmarkFunctionExecution(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Benchmark benchmark) throws Throwable {
        final long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object retVal = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting timed operation");
            retVal = joinPoint.proceed();
            return retVal;
        } finally {
            final long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - startMillis;
            String logMessage = MessageFormat.format("{0} Call to {1} took {2}ms", annotation.description(), joinPoint.getSignature(), duration);
            if(annotation.logReturnValue() && (retVal != null)){
               logMessage += " Returned: " + retVal.toString();
            }
            logger.debug(logMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Invoking on a random function I have declared on an already existing @Service bean that is called from an Endpoint.

```
@Benchmark(logReturnValue = true, description = "Overall Time")
public String dummyFunc() {
    log.info("Attempting to call aspect");
 {
```

Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    "
>

    <!-- enable custom annotations for benchmarking -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <!-- Annotation-driven non-MVC classes -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.tia.extensions,net.tia.sec" />
    <beans profile="ldap">
        <bean id="AuthenticationProvider" class="net.tia.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProviderImpl">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="localUserDetailsService"/>
            <property name="authenticator">
                <bean class="net.tia.authentication.LdapAuthenticatorImpl">
                    <property name="pricipalPattern">
                        <value>tia\#login#</value>
                    </property>
                    <property name="securityContextSource">
                        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
                            <constructor-arg value="ldap://127.0.0.1:452/"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="altAuth">
        <bean id="siteAuthenticationProvider" class="net.tia.authentication.siteAuthenticationProviderImpl">
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="localUserDetailsService"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="singleSignOnIdentityDriver" class="net.tia.authentication.siteIdentityDriver"/>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Comment: Please show us your configuration and a sample method invocation.

Comment: ah wait it might be the config, I thought the system already had it enabled as it had 

 `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:include name="transactionAdvice"/>
  <!--<aop:include name="profiler"/>-->
 </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>`

but this might not apply to what I'm doing.

Comment: Updated my config with `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`, still doesn't work.  I'm going to play around with the config a bit since this is in a large project, but is my syntax correct for the `@Around`? I saw people say many different ways of doing that

Answer (score 1):

> is my syntax correct for the `@Around`?

The syntax is defined in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts).

You've provided

```
execution(@net.tia.util.aspects.Benchmark * *(..)), && @annotation(Benchmark)
```

For one, the `,` is invalid. Second, the `execution` is unnecessary. Spring AOP pointcuts can only match method invocations and you seem to want all methods (`public` really), the use of `@annotation` is equivalent to the `execution` you're trying to use.

Since you also want to use the annotation in your joinpoint, all you need is

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)")
```

where the `annotation` within parentheses refers to your method parameter.

Here's a complete example

```
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Sample.class);
        ctx.getBean(Foo.class).dummyFunc();
    }
}

@Component
class Foo {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    @Benchmark
    public String dummyFunc() {
        logger.info("real method");
        return "sads";
    }
}

@Component
@Aspect
class BenchmarkAspect {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BenchmarkAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "@annotation(benchmark)")
    public Object benchmarkFunctionExecution(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Benchmark benchmark) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("intercepted");
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface Benchmark {
}
```

Comment: Ah yea I read some more and saw that, I tried this `@Around(value = "@annotation(benchmark)")` after changing the variable name to match and it still didn't get picked up.  I'm going to play more with the config.  there are just so many moving parts here I'm trying to narrow down where to focus.

Comment: With the config you've, assuming you're loading it correctly and a bunch of other assumptions I've made (I wouldn't have to if you gave a complete example), this works fine.

Comment: Added the configuration, I cant really add everything as its part of a very large application

Comment: So the bean is for sure getting created with the aspect, aop is enabled in the config, we have the following dependency in ivy `<dependency org="org.aspectj" name="aspectjweaver" rev="1.6.12"/>` to weave the aspect in

Comment: @AdamJames What I really want you to post is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), emphasis on the **minimal**. I've posted a complete example that intercepts the annotated method invocation.